# What is the easiest way to test if certain values exist in mutliple arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I know this might seem like hw question, and be my guest to treat it as such because this is a self-learning exercise.

What would be the easiest way to test if certain values exist within mutliple arrays?

**For example:**

Pseudo code

```
if array a contains a value of 4 and
   array b contains a value of 2 and
   array c contains a value of 6 
then procede to procedure x
```

What I have so far in implementation

```
#include<stdio.h>

void x(void){/* do stuff */}

int main()
{
    char fndA = 0;
    char fndB = 0;
    char fndC = 0;

    int a[5] = {1,2,3,5,6};    
    int b[5] = {1,2,2,3,4};
    int c[5] = {1,3,4,5,6};

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==4){fndA=1;}
    }

    //repeat for-loop for b/fndb and c/fndC

    if (fndA && fndB && fndC) {x();}

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, `x()` never gets called because a 4 does not exis in array `a`.  But will I ultimately have to build a `for` loop for each array I want to test?  Thanks

Comment: `if(a[i]=4){fndA=1;}` does not do what you think it does.  I think you meant `if(a[i]==4){fndA=1;}`

Comment: @Corbin corrected.  thx for pointing it out.  c is not my first language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. But you can obviously create a function that does the loop. You need to pass the array, its size and the element you are looking for to that function.

```
int array_contains_int(int *arr, size_t size, int value) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(arr[i] == value)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just for curriosity sake, why did you seperate `int i` from your for-loop?

Comment: @hydroparadise declaration in for-loop is supported only from C99 onwards. I guess it's separated just to make it universal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure someone would have commented exactly that if I used the (nicer) C99 syntax :p

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The code you wrote is basically what you would do.  In general, you seem to be treating arrays as sets, in which case you could think of this as an abstract datatype with the signature of sets.  If instead you had these arrays implemented some other way, you might be able to abstract the `member()` function to have a lower running time, generally O(log(n)) (for a tree based implementation).  However, yes, whatever you do, you will want to do an AND over your `member()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function that takes an int and an array and returns true or false. Then and three of those together.

This has the added benefit of not calling later loops if one of the first one returns false in the condition.